# How to implement "less than operator" for random access iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, operator-overloading, random-access

I'm implementing custom random access stl iterator. Wrapper for ATL-Classes like `CArray`. So I have index instead of pointer. My `end()`-Iterator has index -1.

As i see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) compare operators like "less than" must be implemented.

My question is; what should be the result, if one of the compare argument is an `end()`-Iterator? Is it defined behavior?

VS2015 implements `vector_iterator` like this;

```
bool operator<(const _Myiter& _Right) const
{   // test if this < _Right
    _Compat(_Right);
    return (_Ptr < _Right._Ptr);
}
```

But i'm not sure what will be happend, if `_Right` or `*this` is an `end()`-Iterator.

**Edit**: The idea that `end()` has the index as `-1` was bad. Now i'm using container size as index for `end()`-iterator.

Comment: That's really depends on how is your iterator implemented. There is no code, so, noone can answer this.

Comment: @ForEveR but i''m asking a behavior. Is end() < Iter or Iter < end()? My iterator is an wrapper for ATL-Class. So I have index instead of pointer.

Comment: `end()` is an iterator that 'points' past the last element of a container (since iterators are modeled on pointers and a regular pointer to an array must permit a value that points past the end of the array in a well-defined way),  So any valid iterator to an element of a container will be less than the `end()` iterator for that container.  And when comparing two iterators that both have the value of `end()`, neither will be less than the other. To put it simply, `iter < end()` will be true as long as `iter` refers to an element of the container.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Myiter`, `_Right`, `_Compat`, `_Ptr`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker it is not my code. code is from vector iterator by VS2015. anyway thank you for the info.

Comment: Whoops, sorry; careless reading. Your post does say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael Burr's comments are essentially the correct answer.

`operator<(LeftIter,RightIter)` should be true **if and only if** there is a strictly positive number N such that `LeftIter+N == RightIter`.

For the element at position `P`, `LeftIter` would be `container.begin()+P`, so there indeed is such a number N. It's `container.size()-P`, which is indeed always bigger than 0.

How you implement this is up to you, the Standard just describes the visible behavior.

Comment: Calling `operator<` on iterators from two different containers is Undefined Behavior. As the author of `operator<`, that means you may assume they point to the same container,

Answer (score 2):

1. If `*this` is `end()` iterator, then return false;
2. If `_Right` is `end()` iterator, then return true;
3. In opposite case return result of compare.

And there is a good idea to implement `end()` iterator by way, that function compare has this behaviour, without any special-cases (1-2).

Comment: That should be true, but is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It is documented in a *very* indirect way by the standard in the Iterators library section.  The `<` operator for comparing two iterators is defined in terms of the `-` operator , which is defined in terms of the `+` operator, which is defined in terms of the `+=` operator which is defined in terms of the pre-`++` and `--` operators (of the input and bidirectional iterator varieties).  The input iterator's pre-`++` operator is defined to possibly result in the "past-the-end" iterator value (which is what `end()` returns).  Whew.

Comment: @MichaelBurr that comment is the correct answer to me.